# What’s the impact of too many ORM POJO Domain Model Classes on Java PermGen Space? Are there any metrics available?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jvm, jooq

While using JPA/ORM like Hibernate et al, it is common to define Java beans / POJOs to represent the entities that are mapped to the respective RDBMS tables. However, the platform I am trying to develop involves supporting 200,000 such entities. If I have to go by the standard Spring MVC + Hibernate model, I might end up creating 200K Model POJOs, 200K DAO Classes and another 200K or so JavaBeans containing data in a format that is presentable in Views. This amounts to about 600K Java Classes in addition to the ones required by Spring, Hibernate and a whole lot of other libraries. Assume each POJO Model class has 10 String instance variables and their corresponding getter/setters. Now I would like to know how much of PermGen space is required to load all these classes.

What's the best way to find the PermGen Space overhead? One crazy idea is to write a program to generate these 200K classes, load them (but do not create instances of them) and run a profiler to identify the "Classes without instances" metric and some how get their permgen size.

In fact I am also searching a simpler solution that can do the needful with just a java.util.Map of Field Vs Value Map, where Field contains the metadata about the RDBMS Table/Column Mapping and generating the JDBC CRUD statements (such as with [JOOQ.org](http://www.jooq.org) without overhead of new classes).

The goal is to run the show without having to use too much reflection and load too many classes that just carry data!!

Any help in this matter is really appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but wouldn't be an improvement if you don't write DAO classes and use aspects to inject DAO capabilities into your entities? This will reduce the number of classes to 400k converting 200k of them into aspects. Another optimization could be to avoid the presentation JavaBeans and just convert your entities into JSON and send it to the view, this implies you will be using JavaScript rather than JSP tags to read your "beans"

Answer (score 1):

The impact would be, as you suggest, that PermGen space is exhausted pretty quickly and you get an OutOfMemoryException. With that many classes, you most probably run out of memory using default JVM settings before even starting up your app. (For help in estimating the actual size of your classes in memory, see [Issue 142 of *The Java Specialists' Newsletter*](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue142.html).)

You can of course increase the permgen space from the default (which is low - IIRC something like 80M but I can't find a source for this) via the command line, e.g. `-XX:MaxPermSize=256M`. However, with that many classes you would need several Gigabytes of PermGen space. Our app uses slightly more than 1K classes and we already observed OOME so had to raise the PermGen space limit to 128M. Not to mention that maintenance of that many classes is going to be a nightmare...

So as you conclude, it would be better to find an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks for Dr. Kabutz's newsletter link. I am working on creating a benchmark. I will post my observations and findings, if any.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be very difficult to actually point out the total perm gen space required.as u go on using it, running a visual vm or jmap can indicate the amount of loaded classes. We were also dealing with an application which was this massive and we had allocated around 2048 MB of perm gen space, and we ran into constraints even after that. 
You can try looking up into lazy loading so that not all of them are active, up and running at at the same time, combined with using a c3po.

Comment: Thanks Raveesh. If possible could you please share any data from your profiler in an abstract form as to how may classes could be squeezed into 2GB of permgen?

Comment: I've noticed in productive Weblogic environments, that Weblogic classloaders tend to unload infrequently used classes again, to make room for other classes. If you know that you're hardly going to use all of those classes at the same time, there is some container-based optimisation potential there.

Comment: The amount of classes that can be squeezed in depends on the size of the object. SInce we were using hibernate, put pojo which was associated to the tables contained around 108 columns. In such cases, the amount of perm gen space consumed would increase. It very very difficult to comment on the amount of classes that can be loaded. You can have a million objects even with 1GB perm space.